# What are ancestors in Ruby and what is their use?

Tags: ruby

What are ancestors in Ruby? What are they used for and what is their basic purpose?

Comment: class MySpecialError < RuntimeError                               
  end
                                                                    
  def test_exceptions_inherit_from_Exception                        
    assert_equal RuntimeError, MySpecialError.ancestors[1]          
    assert_equal StandardError, MySpecialError.ancestors[2]         
    assert_equal Exception, MySpecialError.ancestors[3]             
    assert_equal Object , MySpecialError.ancestors[4]               
  end                 

# how the ancestors can be related to the output..RuntimeError, #StandardError etc..???

Answer (score 8):

An ancestor of a class is either the class itself, a module included by any of the class's ancestors or the superclass of any of the class's ancestors. In short the ancestors of a class are all the classes and modules in which ruby will look for the method definition when you call a method on an object of that class.

Similarly a module's ancestors are the module itself and any module included by any of the module's ancestors.

Their purpose is to enable inheritance, which is a basic concept of object oriented programming.